# i need to add a customized button to the toolbar instead of the regular 3 dots menu

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]so im trying to add a floating action button into the tool bar on the top right but all i get is
the button goes to the middle top below the toolbar here's my xml code any chance that can be done because i dont want to use the normal 3 dots menu button i have been looking for a solution for days,
couldn't find what im looking for

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_add_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@id/Plus"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        >

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_add_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/FindPeople"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >
    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_start_group_24"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:id="@+id/startGroup"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/Blue"
        android:visibility="invisible">

    </com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton>



</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

now it's showing like this i just need 1 button in the far right of the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of the main `Toolbar` layout to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`. I have tried and this positions the button to the top right of the screen as you most probably want.
And in your first `FloatingActionButton`, you should have the `id` as `android:id="@+id/Plus"` instead of `android:id="@id/Plus"`

Comment: it didnt work as u can see in the image now it's showing 2 button the one in the toolbar doens't work the one below it does, i just need to place it in the far right of the toolbar next to the WizChat name :)